# Compare multiple rows and merge into one row

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table with 4 columns.I need to merge the rows into one record if the difference of the end_date and start_date of the next row is less than 120 days difference. This merge should be for each name.

[image]

Please see the expected results below

[image]

Comment: Does the ranges can overlap? does the adjacent records (where end_date(1) = start_date(2) - 120 days) must be linked?

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id, name, start_date, end_date
FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT test.id, test.name, test.start_date, cte.end_date
FROM test, cte
WHERE cte.start_date BETWEEN test.start_date AND DATEADD(day, 120, test.end_date)
  AND test.name = cte.name
  AND test.id < cte.id
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       start_date, 
       end_date,
       MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name, end_date) xstart_date, 
       MAX(end_date)  OVER (PARTITION BY name, start_date) xend_date
FROM cte
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name, xend_date) id,
       name,
       MIN(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name, xend_date) start_date,
       MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name, xend_date) end_date
FROM cte2
ORDER BY id
```